# dynamically build menu filename

Tags: android, menu

I have multiple menu files menu_language_en, menu_language_es...etc
I would like to load them using another variable, something like:

```
String lang="en";
inflater.inflate(eval("R.menu.language_menu_"+lang), menu);
```

Any idea??

Thanks
jo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer is to use [resource sets](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html), so you have a single filename in different directories based on language (e.g., `res/menu/options.xml`, `res/menu-de/options.xml`, `res/menu-zh/options.xml`, etc.). You, in your code, just `inflate(R.menu.options, menu)`, and Android chooses the right language based on the user's locale.

If for some reason that solution is unsuitable, use `getResources().getIdentifier()` to derive the resource ID given the name, then use that value with your call to `inflate()`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but that doesn't suit my needs at all! It's for a translation app, the language selected is not related to the user's locale. And moreover, I'm really interested in dynamic naming, could be for menus R.menu.thing$y, but any other ressource, eg: R.xml.example_n$num